# ¿Como ejecutar un método desde otra clase y no perder los datos de TextBox Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lleno un formulario e invoco un **login** para validar los permisos de usuario, para permitir eliminar un registro:

```
private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           Autenticar autenticar = new Autenticar();
           autenticar.ShowDialog();
      }
```

después desde la Clase `Autenticar` invoco el método para eliminar registros:

```
public void Autentica()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn =
                    new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-0J5JMUG;Initial Catalog=Admin Test;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlDataAdapter sda =
                    new SqlDataAdapter(
                        "Select count (*) from tblUsuario where NombreUsuario='" + txtUsuario.Text + "' and Contraseña= '" +
                        txtContraseña.Text + "'", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    this.Hide();

                    **EditarCompra eliminar = new EditarCompra();**
                    **eliminar.EliminarCompra();**
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El usuario o la contraseña son necesarios para poder 'eliminar una compra'");
                }
            }
```

La situación es que cuando recorre el método, no toma en cuenta los valores de los textbox que había en la pantalla.

```
 public void EliminarCompra()
        {

          try
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }

                SqlCommand connCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_ListCompra_EliminaCompra", conn);
                connCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                connCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCompra", Convert.ToInt32(this.txtId.Text));
                connCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Se Eliminó Exitosamente");
                Reset();
                FilldtgBuscaCompra();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mensaje de Error");
            }
        }
```

Ademas de que no ejecuta los métodos `Reset()` y  `FilldtgBuscaCompra()` ya que no detecta los valores que incluyen.

Answer (score 1):

[Y porque no se lo pasas por parametros?](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters) :

```
public void Autentica(string nombre, string pass, string idCompra)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn =
                    new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-0J5JMUG;Initial Catalog=Admin Test;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlDataAdapter sda =
                    new SqlDataAdapter(
                        "Select count (*) from tblUsuario where NombreUsuario='" + nombre + "' and Contraseña= '" +
                        pass + "'", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    this.Hide();

                    ditarCompra eliminar = new EditarCompra();
                    eliminar.EliminarCompra(idCompra);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El usuario o la contraseña son necesarios para poder 'eliminar una compra'");
                }
            }

public void EliminarCompra(string idCompra)
{

      try
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand connCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_ListCompra_EliminaCompra", conn);
            connCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCompra", Convert.ToInt32(idCompra));
            connCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Se Eliminó Exitosamente");
            Reset();
            FilldtgBuscaCompra();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mensaje de Error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar métodos de otra clase tienes que crear un objeto.

`Form1` es donde recolectas la información, supongamos que son dos `TextBox`

`Form2` es donde esta el método que quieres ocupar, el nombre del método seria `ejemplo`

una manera facil seria asi

```
form2 obj = new form2();
obj.ejemplo(textbox1.Text,textbox2.Text);
```

en el form2 tienes que tener tu metodo de esta forma

```
public void ejemplo(string dato1, string dato2){

}
```

espero, entiendas

Answer (score 0):

Se requiere pasar la instancia del formulario "Padre" al formulario "Hijo", de no ser así no sabrás de que formulario viene la llamada de tu ventana Hijo

Realiza este ejercicio:

- Crea un formulario Padre, llamado MainForm con un textBox, en este
  caso el nombre es textBox1 y un botón con su evento clic (el nombre
  del botón no importa).
- Crea un formulario Hijo, llamale FormAux (formulario auxiliar), en el
  coloca un boton con su evento clic, ahorita le agregamos la lógica.

crea una variable a nivel de clase (en el formulario hijo) de tipo MainForm,:

```
MainForm fMain = new MainForm();
```

- Ahora en el constructor del formulario hijo (FormAux) indica que recibirás una instancia del formulario MainForm esto se hace de esta manera y ademas asigna el parámetro recibido a tu variable fMain:

  public FormAux(MainForm mainFormParameter)
        {

  InitializeComponent();
  fMain = mainFormParameter;

  ```
    }
  ```

De regreso en el formulario padre - MainForm crea un método llamado Eliminar y que sea publico, que sera el que invoquemos desde el formulario Hijo (tu formulario de login, si lo quieres ver así):

```
  public void  Eliminar()
        {
            //Elimina las cosas

            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

Ahora en el evento clic del botón del formulario Main llamas al formulario hijo y le pasas la instancia actual de tu ventana (**new FormAux(this)**):

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormAux form = new FormAux(this);
            form.Show();
        }
```

Finalmente en tu formulario hijo en el evento clic del unico botón que tienes mandas a llamar la función Eliminar de tu formulario que se encuentra almacenando en la varialbe fmain:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fMain.Eliminar();
        }
```